# Suddenly Unable to launch application using JNLP

Tags: java, jnlp

I am facing a strange problem, we have been launching application using JNLP on Windows machine with JDK/JRE 1.7. This has been working fine so far, suddenly JNLP is not working.

Tried with JRE 1.8 as well, same issue. On start I see the JRE launch screen and then it closes.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.  Is the app. digitally signed using a valid certificate from a CA?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, the application is not signed one at this point of time. Could sort out this issue by deleting following folder: C:\Users\%USER_NAME%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment